# How to override the stack trace template in django?

Tags: python, django, exception, django-templates

How can I change the template that django uses to display a stack trace when DEBUG mode is enabled and an exception gets caught at the top of the stack resulting in a 500?

Apologies if this is a dupe question -- I'm sure the answer is stated simply somewhere, but owing to the nature of the search terms I'm having a hard time tracking down the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the trace is formatted by an internal template in `views/debug.py`. Look for TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE and for get_traceback_html() where it's used. So you could copy that template, hack it as you like, then monkeypatch it into django.view.debug. It ain't pretty, but this is fairly deep into the guts so you have to expect to get some "stuff" on you.

Answer (score 1):

Define a [`handler500`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#handler500) in the URLconf.

Comment: That requires me to write my own view.  Is there a way I can just modify the standard template?